# Suppose that $\det(A) = 1$ , show $A=I$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $\det(A) = 1$ , show $A=I$?

How to proof this question??

I tried like that

$\det(A)=1 , \det(I)=1  $

Comment: This is false, put whatever you want above the diagonal of an upper triangular matrix with 1's on the diagonal

Comment: Even if you constrain $A$ to be diagonal, this is false. Consider e.g. the $2 \times 2$ matrix $A = -I$. More generally, let $A$ be any diagonal matrix, the product of whose diagonal entries equals $1$.

Comment: $$ \det \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 7 & 8 \\ 6 & 7 \end{array} \right] = 1. $$ There are many matrices whose determinant is $1. \qquad$

Comment: It is more or less like saying that if a number is odd, it is $37$.

Comment: $A=I\implies \det(A)=1$, not $A=I\iff \det(A)=1$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not true.

Just consider the matrix

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$$

Clearly $\det(A)=1$, but $A\neq I$

Answer (score 3):

Counterexample $$A=\begin{pmatrix}2 & 1 \\ 3 & 2\end{pmatrix}$$